# SQL Server convert into time Series for Grafana

Tags: sql-server, plugins, grafana

At the moment I am trying to create a pie chart in Grafana, but for that I would have to convert my code into timeseries.

Since it is required to have a column with "time" in it so I can use this plugin.
I only want to show e.g. % amount of updates or simple integers
Does anyone know if and how to do that? Is it even possible?

I tried

```
Select CAST(nn.ComputerID AS NVARCHAR(36))[Computer ID], client.ComputerName , count(*) as [number Software] From oems_client_nn_software as nn
Left Join oems_client as client on client.ComputerID = nn.ComputerID
GROUP BY nn.ComputerID, client.ComputerName
```

I Found :

```
SELECT
  GETUTCDATE() AS time,
  COUNT(*) AS measurement,
  CASE statusId
    WHEN 0 THEN 'pending'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'running'
    ...
    ELSE 'something else'
  END AS outcome
FROM
  BPASession
GROUP BY
  statusid
```

I tried it, but I think I'm not good enough to understand that.

Lets hope someone can help me.

Comment: Don't you have any date-time column or epoch value as a column in your table?

Comment: @SenalWeerasinghe


    SELECT TOP [ComputerID]
          ,[SoftwareID]
          ,[Installed] // this has date too
          ,[LastSeen] // this could be date
          ,[InstanzID]
          ,[InstallSource]
      FROM [omes].[dbo].[oems_client_nn_software]
      
      maybe with thise one?

Comment: can you upload an image of a select query for all the columns that you used in the above query? I want to check the data type of these columns.

Comment: you mean like this?
Those are all uniqueIDs, thats why i had to CAST ( NVARCHAR ..) 
https://www.bilder-upload.eu/bild-966065-1588069307.png.html